# Parsing a log file using perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I have a log file where some of the entries look like this:

```
YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS:MMM <Some constant text> v1=XXX v2=YYY v3=ZZZ v4=AAA AND BBB v5=CCC
```

and I'm trying to get it into a CSV format:

```
Date,Time,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
YY/MM/DD,HH:MM:SS:MMM,XXX,YYY,ZZZ,AAA AND BBB,CCC
```

I'd like to do this in Perl - speaking personally, I could probably do it far quicker in other languages but I'd really like to expand my horizons a bit.

So far I can get as far as reading the file in and picking out only lines which meet my criteria but I can't seem to get the next stage done. I'll need to splice up the input line but so far I just can't work out how to do this. I've looked at `s//`and `m//` but they don't really give me what I want. If anyone can advise me how this can be done or give me pointers I'd much appreciate it.

**Important points:**

- The values in the second part of the line are always in the same order so mapping / re-organising is not necesarily a problem.
- Some of the fields have free text which is not quoted :( but as the labels all start `v<number>=` I'm hoping parsing this should still be a possibility.

Comment: How does `m//` not give you what you need? This looks like a perfect case for regular expressions.

Comment: @Wooble I tried m// and it gave me back 1 (i.e. true / false? ) - I guess I just couldn't figure out how to use it from the examples I found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no one delimiter, you'll need to try this a few different ways:

First, split on `' '`, then take the first three values:

```
my @array = split / /, $line;
my ($date, $time, $constant) = splice @array, 0, 3;
```

Join the rest of the fields together again, and re-split on `v\d+=` to get the values:

```
my $rest = join ' ', @array;

# $rest should now be "v1=XXX v2=YYY ..."
my @values = split /\s*v\d+=/, $rest;
shift @values; # since the first element in @values will be empty

print join ',', $date, $time, @values;
```

**Edit**: Here's another approach that may be easier to follow, and is slightly more efficient. This takes advantage of the fact that your constant text occurs between the date/time and the value list.

```
# assume that CONSTANT is your constant text
my ($datetime, $valuelist) = split /\s*CONSTANT\s*/, $line;
my ($date, $time) = split / /, $datetime;
my @values = split /\s*v\d+=/, $valuelist;
shift @values;

print join ',', $date, $time, @values, "\n";
```

Comment: The split on space will mess v4 up, because it contains embedded spaces.

Comment: @Dave, that's why I added `join ' ', @array` before attempting to split on the `v\d=`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I gave your first approach a try and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried with regular expressions and how has it failed?  A regex with `m//` works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Date,Time,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5\n";

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @matched = $line =~ m{^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+).*v1=(.*) v2=(.*) v3=(.*) v4=(.*) v5=(.*)};
    print join(',', @matched), "\n";
}

__DATA__
YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS:MMM <Some constant text> v1=XXX v2=YYY v3=ZZZ v4=AAA AND BBB v5=CCC
```

Two caveats:

1) v1 cannot contain the substring " v2=", v2 cannot contain " v3=", etc., but, with such a loose format, that's something that would likely cause problems for a human attempting to parse it, too.

2) This code assumes that there will always be v1 through v5.  If there are fewer than five v*n* fields, the line will fail to match.  If there are more, all additional fields will be appended to v5 (including their v*n* tags).

Comment: This assumes that the value list always contains exactly 5 values. If that assumption holds, then this works fine, but the match will fail if we ever have a different list than that.

Comment: @JSBangs: Good point.  Edited to make that assumption explicit.

Comment: That's clever. Must admit I did not know about `m{}` Thanks.

Comment: @Robin: Keep in mind that m{} and s{}{} are _exactly_ the same as m// and s/// aside from not needing to escape / characters. I just opted for the {} delimiters to avoid a lot of \/\/\/ when matching the date, then decided to match it without worrying about the slashes anyhow...

Answer (score 1):

In case the log is fixed-width, you better off using `unpack`, you will see its benefits if the log grows very large (performance wise).